# Does Redission support pipelining to redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redisson

Does Redission support pipelining to redis cluster?

RBatch in redission can be used to perform multiple hmset commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, redisson `RBatch batch = client.createBatch()` does the pipelining in Redis cluster mode.

Verified this on redis cluster mode by submitting multiple `fastPutAsync` commands on single batch.